# How to extract the web address from html string using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract the web address from this string:

```
<p> Feb 24 - <a href="http://austin.daylife.org/apa/2867907745.html">$390 / 2br - 600ft&sup2; - Sleeps 4-Walk to SXSW-SOCO-Perfect Location</a> - <font size="-1"> (South 5th)</font> <span class="p"> pic</span></p>
```

How can I achieve the same using regular expression in C#?

Comment: I tried this bu failed  <a[^>]*? href=\"(?<url>[^\"]+)\"[^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?
```

**EDIT:** Simpler expression:

```
http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?
```

Comment: i am not getting any matches, If this fromat is applicable in C#  Is the any tool present to generate the expression.

Comment: Try the simpler version above.

Comment: Thanks Roy its works me fine... can i ask one more doubt?? If i need to parse multiple tags what should i do?? For example userbody inside <div> tag..href etc. Please help me...

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is difficult and often error-prone. You would do better by using an HTML parser library instead, such as the HTML Agility Pack at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
        string source = " <p> Feb 24 - <a href=\"http://austin.daylife.org/apa/2867907745.html\">$390 / 2br - 600ft&sup2; - Sleeps 4-Walk to SXSW-SOCO-Perfect Location</a> - <font size=\"-1\"> (South 5th)</font> <span class=\"p\"> pic</span></p> ";
        Regex regex = new Regex("<a[^>]*? href=\"(?<url>[^\"]+)\"[^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>");
        var m = regex.Match(source);
        string url = m.Groups["url"];
```